# Nginx rewrite with Server_name as underscore

Tags: linux, nginx, rewrite

We have nginx config with server_name as underscore. How do I rewrite from http to https.

```
server {
server_name _;
rewrite ^/(.*) https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
}
```

This returns error as http://_/ do not found. Any way not to give domain name in the rewrite rule.

Comment: Why are you using `server_name _` and requesting `http://_` at all?

Comment: What is the exact thing you are trying to achieve? Give a concrete example what should happen.

Comment: My telepathy says, that you need `$host` or `$http_host`.

Comment: It seams that the underscore `_` is set in the nginx default configuration at least in debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a nginx block to listen on port 80 to redirect everything to https. Place the usual configuration in the 443 block.

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    _;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
   listen         443 ssl;
   server_name    _;

   [....]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem lies in the inability to resolve `_` (this is the primary reason why you get "not found" error after sussessful redirect), not in nginx config file.
Make your own TLD zone for `_`, or at least add a record in `/etc/hosts`.